# GD Shadow to Black or Transparent Background

Tags: php, gd

I'm using Andrew G. Johnson's imagettftextblur() and it's great but how does one add a shadow that blends from the text color to a black background or to do so dynamically to any background color on a transparent image? If I set the shadow to black it disappears, while setting it to a lighter color looks like a blob. Against a white background it looks great but not against black or other dark colors.

The code I'm using is as follows and calls several custom functions including imagettftextblur() but the others are unrelated to the question. I tried to post a sample image but was unable.

function textimage($Strings,$Fonts,$FontSize,$Angle,$EnableShadow,$CenterAlign) {

```
$FontPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/functions/truetype/";

if (is_array($Strings) === TRUE && is_array($Fonts) === TRUE) :
    foreach (array_combine($Strings, $Fonts) AS $Strings => $Fonts) :
        $Fonts = $FontPath.$Fonts.".ttf";
        $TextDimensions = imagettfbbox($FontSize,$Angle,$Fonts,$Strings);
        $Width = abs($TextDimensions[4] - $TextDimensions[0] + 5);
        $Height = abs($TextDimensions[5] - $TextDimensions[1]) + 10;
        $Image = imageCreateTransparent($Width,$Height);
        $TextColor = imagecolorallocate($Image,255,204,153);
        $ShadowColor = imagecolorallocate($Image,119,119,119);
        $y_offset = abs($TextDimensions[5]);
        if ($EnableShadow === TRUE):
            if ($CenterAlign === TRUE):
                $x_offset = CenterText($FontSize,$Fonts,$Strings,$Width);
            else:
                $x_offset = ($Width / 2) - ((min($TextDimensions[2],$TextDimensions[4]) - max($TextDimensions[0],$TextDimensions[6])) / 2);
            endif;
            imagettftextblur($Image,$FontSize,$Angle,$x_offset+5,$y_offset+5,$ShadowColor,$Fonts,$Strings,10);
            imagettftextblur($Image,$FontSize,$Angle,$x_offset,$y_offset,$TextColor,$Fonts,$Strings);
        else:
            if ($CenterAlign === TRUE):
                $x_offset = CenterText($FontSize,$Fonts,$Strings,$Width);
            else:
                $x_offset = ($Width / 2) - ((min($TextDimensions[2],$TextDimensions[4]) - max($TextDimensions[0],$TextDimensions[6])) / 2);
            endif;
            imagettftext($Image,$FontSize,$Angle,$x_offset,$y_offset,$TextColor,$Fonts,$Strings);
        endif;
    endforeach;
endif;

return imagepng($Image);
imagedestroy($Image);
```

}

I am calling it using a separate script:

header('Content-Type: image/png');

require("logo_functions.php");

```
$Strings = array("Packard ","/ IMPERIAL page");
$Fonts = array("racew17","timesbd");
$Size = 20;
$Angle = 0;
$Shadow = TRUE;
$CenterAlign = TRUE;
```

echo textimage($Strings,$Fonts,$Size,$Angle,$Shadow,$CenterAlign);

Comment: Post code and image of what you are getting and I will give you my thoughts

Comment: Posted above but I am unable to post an image.